# Not able to import Kotlin object into xml

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a DateUtils class which looks like this

```
object DateUtils {
    private val DATE_FORMAT = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
    fun parseDate(date: Date): String {
        return DATE_FORMAT.format(date)
    }
}
```

Imorting and using DateUtils in xml like this fails

```
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <data>
  <import type="com.xpns.utils.DateUtils"/>
  <import type="android.view.View" />                    
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView        
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"                      
 android:text="@{@string/item_date(DateUtils.parseDate(viewModel.date))}"/>
```

getting following error

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method parseDate(java.lang.String) in class com.xpns.utils.DateUtils
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try adding `@JvmStatic` to `formatDate()` in the `DateUtils` definition and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, I forgot adding JvmStatic apart from type error of method name.

Answer (score 3):

You've defined a function called `formatDate()` but trying to call a function called `parseDate()`, so you just need to change where you call the function to `formatDate()` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @shekar this is correct silly mistake that you have done.

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing out the typo but the main issue was I missed adding @JvmStatic.